# How to export the response data obtained from a GET API using fetch from one module to another

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

Code Snippet:

```
let data ={};

zlFetch('http://localhost:3000/new.json')
        .then(response =>  handleget(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

function handleget(response)
{
   data = response.body;
}

export default data
```

Now i would like to export this data so that i can import the same in other code.

Now I know that since resolving the promise is asynchronous the data will be {}.
But if i try to export from inside the handleget function then i get an error saying import export should be in top level of the document.

So  how can i extract the data from a fetch response and store it in a variable outside the then() scope and then export it else where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

It is asynchronous.

The export of the value of `data` happens **before** the response has been received.

Assign the promise returned from `catch` to `data` instead.

Then deal with the promise after you import it.

```
const data = zlFetch('http://localhost:3000/new.json')
        .then(response =>  resonse.body)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

export default data;
```

Later

```
import newthing from './myModule';
newthing.then(data => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks! Was banging my head against the wall. Guess i need some more time to wrap my head around this asynchronous part of JS

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer provided by Quentin, here  is how my final code looks like along with error handling from fetch request

```
//Logic.js
const data = zlFetch('http://localhost:3000/new.json')
        .then(response =>  response)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

export default data

//App.js
import data from "./Logic.js";

async function fetch_this_data()
    {
        const res = await data.then(result => result);
        
            if (res.status == 200)
            {
                console.log("res"+JSON.stringify(res.body));
                return res.body;
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("resu"+JSON.stringify(res));
                return "Error!! Status "+res.status;
            }
        
    }

fetch_this_data();
```