# Export data obtained by an asynchronous operation from a module using module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

Is there a way to export data obtained by an asynchronous operation from a module in Node.js?

*Example:*

```js
function sendArray() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }, 5000);
  });
}

async function fetchArray() {
  const myArray = await sendArray();
}
```

Can I export `myArray` from this module?

Comment: why not export the `fetchArray` function itself?

Comment: Because I don't want to fetch the result in other modules every time. Say I have multiple modules where I need just the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export the response data obtained from a GET API using fetch from one module to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563912/how-to-export-the-response-data-obtained-from-a-get-api-using-fetch-from-one-mod)

Comment: So we cannot do that?

Comment: You can do it if you really want to but the problem is that any consumer won't know *when* the data is actually available. So the better solution is to export a promise or a function that returns a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling Still I want to know how. Can you show me?

Comment: You can do `export let result;` and simply assign to `result` at any point in time to update/change the value. Any code that imported `result` will have access to the new value. But again, they won't know *when* `result` has the updated value.

Comment: Can you restructure my example to illustrate? @FelixKling

Comment: `export let myArray; async function fetchArray() { myArray = await sendArray(); }`.

Comment: @FelixKling throwing an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using ES6 modules. Then it's even easier you can just assign to `modules.exports.myArray`.